# First steps in creating a chroma key effect using android camera

Tags: android, image-processing, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, android-camera

I'd like to create a chroma key effect using the android camera. I don't need a step by step, but I'd like to know the best way to hijack the android camera and apply the filters. I've checked out the API and haven't found anything super definitive on how to manipulate data coming from the camera. At first I looked into using a surface texture, but I'm not fully aware how that helps or how to even use it. Then I checked out using a GLSurfaceView, which may be the right direction, but not really sure.

Also, to add to my question, how would I handle both preview and saving of the image? Would I process the image at minimum, twice? Once while previewing and once while saving? I think that's probably the best solution.

Lastly, would it make sense to create a C/++ wrapper to handle the processing to optimize speed?

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. A link to some examples would also be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583820/adding-effect-to-an-android-camera-preview

Comment: Do you need some more details in my answer?

Comment: @Jaa-c Nope. Sorry for the late approval, didn't realize my question had answers until today. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only real chance is to use openGL ES and fragment shader (it will require at least openGL ES 2.0) and do the chroma key effect on GPU. The shader itself will be quite easy (google).

But to do that, you need to display camera preview with callback. You will have to implement [`Camera.PreviewCallback`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html), create a buffer for image data and use `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer` method. You can get the basic idea from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8372731/683905) to a similar question. Note that there is a significant problem with performance of this custom camera preview, but it might work on hardware that supports ES 2.0.

To display the preview with openGL, you will need to extend [`GLSurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html) and also implement `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`. Then you will bind the camera preview frame as a texture with `glTexImage2D` to some simple rectangle and the rest will be handled by shaders. See how to use shaders in ES [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850025/shader-for-android-opengl-es) or if you have no experience with shaders, [this tutorial](http://blog.shayanjaved.com/2011/03/13/shaders-android/) might be a good start.

To the other question: you could save the current image from the preview, but the preview has lower resolution than a taken picture, so you will probably want to take a picture and then process it separately (you could use the same shader for it).

As for the C++, it's a lot of additional effort with questionable output. But it can improve performance if done right. Try to check this [article,](http://nhenze.net/?p=253) it's on a similar topic, it describes how to use NDK to process camera preview and display it in openGL. But if you were thinking about doing the chroma key effect in C++, it would be significantly slower than shaders.

Comment: the original "tutorial" link is dead. After some googling, I found another version of it here: https://pixelp3.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/shaders-android/

Comment: @Jaa-c I ended up going the route of OpenGL. I did things a little differently, though. You don't need to have a buffer of pixels. Android allows you to push the camera pixels to an OES texture using setPreviewTexture.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this library: https://github.com/cyberagent/android-gpuimage.
It provides a framework to do image processing on device's GPU using GL shaders.
There is also a sample showing how to use the library with a camera.

Answer (score 2):

There is  a Chroma-Key-Project on Google-Code: http://code.google.com/p/chroma-key-project/ It includes a way to upload pictures that are token using chroma-key:

> After an exhaustive search online, I have failed to find any open source projects working >with Chroma-keying for Android devices. The aim of this project is to provide a useful >Chroma-key library, that will make it easy to implement applications and games that can take >pictures in front of a Green or Blue screen, and apply the pictures on a chosen background. >Furthermore, the application will also allow the user to upload the picture using Intent.