# How To make Video Background transparent In ExoPlayer Android

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I want to remove background color of video in exoplayer or make it transparent i.e if video background color is red then make it transparent and view behind exoplayer must be visible.

**Note** : I don't want to make changes in Exoplayer background only remove video background which is playing in ExoPlayer

I have made lots of search in google but unfortunate did't got right answer, Please let me know its possible or not and its possible using any other way please direct me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: why dont you use ffmpeg. Then you remove the background, save it and then load it

Answer (score 1):

Exoplayer is not really designed to modify a video file like this while displaying it.

Given that the background may change from frame to frame, I suspect you may find it hard to find any solution that will be able to do this quickly enough on any regular Android device, as there will likely be quite a bit of video processing involved.

If your background is static, like the room behind the speaker in a Zoom or similar conference call, then it may be a bit easier and you could look at OpenCV background substitution techniques:

- https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html

Most of the examples will be in Python so you will have to explore support in Android OpenCV, which is usually a subset and can be a little tricky to set up (check Q&A on SO for this). Android OpenCV also still uses Eclipse rather than Studio in the documentation at the time of writing, which is something to be aware of.

If you have the luxury of removing the background on the server side before you stream the video to the Android device then things will be easier and you should be able to find up to date example using Python and the OpenCV techniques linked above.

If you use case is a 'Greenscreen' background example, then ffmpeg can also provide you filters to change the background as you wish, including making it transparent. The documentation is here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-chromakey

It includes an example to change the green screen to transparent in an image (png image in this example):

> ffmpeg -i input.png -vf chromakey=green out.png

Comment: What if you play WEBM video that has transparency? Would it show it with transparent background, so what's behind would be visible?

Comment: @androiddeveloper - I have not tried it myself but there is a note there that it can work, albeit with some pre-processing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67459184/334402

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. As you wrote, it requires pre-processing, and so it requires a library in the app ( ffmpeg) which changes the license. Isn't there a solution that can handle WEBM as it is?